# How do you handle HTML booleans in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, boolean, server-side-rendering

In most programming languages a boolean value is either `true` or `false`. In HTML on the other hand, native booleans are often represented in the browser with an empty string if true. An example of this would be `<video autoplay="" loop="" />`.

I have a custom web component that uses HTML booleans, and I wonder how to type them correctly. Of course I could just let the user treat them as regular booleans, but in SSR contexts this leads to hydration errors where Node reads "true" while the client reads "".

Comment: HTML is not a programming language, it's a protocol. As it, HTML doesn't have types or booleans. It depends on every attribute.

Comment: Sure, but when a programming language or a scripting language, like JavaScript, outputs HTML markup it's being read differently by browsers than it is by non-browsers. TypeScript has types for different HTML elements, and I'm wondering if there is a type that covers the way boolean HTML attributes are being handled in browsers?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Typescript, and HTML does not really support booleans.

But HTML does support property shorthand in a boolean like way. This is often used for checkboxes like:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

And if you pass any attribute, then then it appears to get serialized as an empty string.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('foo')
const val = el.getAttribute('bar')
console.log(JSON.stringify(val)) // logs: ""
```

```html
<div id="foo" bar>baz</div>
```

So I think you want to instruct the consumers of your component to do:

```
<mycomponent myboolprop />
```

And you would check it as any value, including an empty string.

Comment: OK, so it's a quirk. The problem with the shorthand is that Node.js will interpret it as `true`, while a browser will serialize it as an empty string – producing a hydration error in Next/Nuxt and the likes. It's not a big deal, I guess, I was just curious if there was a way to avoid it. 